# Subquery giving multiple rows error in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table with city names, and 2 time stamp rows, and I need to display the average difference between these 2 time stamp rows for 2 different periods, per city. I am using the following query:

Sample Data

| city_name | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | abc | xyz |
| ABC | qwe | rty |
| XYZ | asd | xyz |
| POI | abc | dfg |

```
select city_name,
(select avg(datediff(date1, date2)) from table1 where date2 between '2022-04-29' and '2022-05-04' group by city_name),
(select avg(datediff(date1, date2)) from table1 where date2 between '2022-04-01' and '2022-05-06' group by city_name)
from table1;
```

The output should look something like:

|city_name  |   Avg_diff_1  |   Avg_diff_2 |
|-----------|---------------|--------------|
|  XYZ      |      2        |      3       |
|  ABC      |      4        |      0       |
|  ...      |     ...       |     ...      |
Can anyone help me identify the issue and provide possible solutions?

Comment: Please add table definition,sample data and desired outcome as text

Answer (score 3):

To make your exact current approach work, you need to correlate the city name inside the subqueries to the value in the outer query.  So, use this version:

```sql
SELECT city_name,
       (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(date1, date2)) FROM table1 b
        WHERE date2 BETWEEN '2022-04-29' AND '2022-05-04' AND
              b.city_name = a.city_name),
       (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(date1, date2)) FROM table1 b
        WHERE date2 BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-05-06' AND
              b.city_name = a.city_name)
FROM table1 a;
```

However, a more common way to write your query might use a single pass over the table along with conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    city_name,
    AVG(CASE WHEN date2 BETWEEN '2022-04-29' AND '2022-05-04'
             THEN DATEDIFF(date1, date2) END),
    AVG(CASE WHEN date2 BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-05-06'
             THEN DATEDIFF(date1, date2) END)
FROM table1
GROUP BY city_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is there a way to optimize the query since the database is pretty huge?

Comment: For the second query, an index on `(city_name, date2, date1)` might help performance.